# SQL Server query to get a pre-position No

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write SQL query, that will display in a new column a 'pre-position number' with values displayed based on the value on the previous position number column row.

[image: See image for more details]

I would appreciate any assistance.
Thank you.

Comment: share text sample data and expected output

Comment: Most people here want sample data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: what is the logic here ?

Comment: Hint : try lag()

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for LAG(). For this to work, you need a column that can be used to *order* the data, so your RDBMS can assess which record is the *previous* record to the current one. Assuming that this column is called id, then:

```
SELECT
    id,
    position_nr,
    LAG(position_nr) OVER(ORDER BY id) pre_position_nr
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `LAG()`.  To get the `0`, use the three argument form:

```
SELECT position_no,
       LAG(position_no, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY position_no) as pre_position_no
FROM mytable;
```

This assumes that you are ordering by `position_no`, as suggested by your sample code.